# Improving the dithering of the gif image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I was having a question between this [gif](https://dribbble.com/shots/1546612-Synchronise) and my work:
[image]

Is it possible to get the better quality of dithering of colors on the first gif to my work? Btw, I did this on Ps via frame animations with the default profile of:

-Selective

-Diffusion

-Uncheck transparency

-Uncheck interlaced

-Check convert to sRGB

-Colors: 256

-Dither: 100%

-Matte: 0%

-Web Snap: 0%

-Lossy: 0

-Quality: 100%

-Quality: Bicubic

Btw, comparing about these two animated gifs, the first one has really smooth dithering of colors unlike my work with full of dead pixels :/ Hope someone can help me about this or give suggestions, thanks alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gif at your link uses **flat colors**. There's not a single gradient anywhere in that gif. You're image has a **ton** of gradients of varying colors. That's the difference.

**Gifs are designed for flat color, gradients will always be dithered to a degree.**

In order to use gradients in a gif well, you really need as many colors in the gif color table as possible. Since 256 colors is the maximum for the gif's "index" color mode. You can only go so far for quality.

If you have several gradients, all of different colors, pulling off smooth dithered transitions with only 256 colors may be impossible.

So to answer your question, to improve quality and make dithering less prominent, you need to remove some gradients (if not all gradients) from your image. If removing gradients is not an option for you, you'll need to learn to live with the dithering or use some other animation method, png sprites with jquery animation for example.

Comment: Oh so that's why it's happening like that. I'm currently using a gradient on the navigation bar on the bottom so meaning even if the gradient is away from the respective positions of the colors, it will still affect the quality of the other colors? am I right? So the solution so far is to only use pure flat colors on the whole illustration to achieve the smooth dithering appearance of the result of an animated gif? Sorry for the bad grammar, thanks alot for helping me!